# RxJava преобразовать две модели в одну

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Получаю курс иностранных валют к рублю https://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=28/03/2020

Модель ответа с сервера:

```
public class RateCurrencyResponseModel {
    private String id;
    private String name; // Например, USD
    private String charCode;
    private String value; // Текущий курс RUB к USD: 75.60
}
```

Модель для работы в UI слое:

```
public class RateCurrencyUiModel {
    private long id;
    private String name; // Например USD
    private String charCode;
    private double value; // Текущий курс RUB к USD: 75.60
    private String change; // Разница со вчерашним курсом: "+0.20"
}
```

К данным сервера обращаюсь через Retrofit 2 и получаю источник данных:

```
Single<List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>>
```

**Задача**

Нужно преобразовать модель ответа сервера, в модель для работы в UI слое.

Т.е.

```
Single<List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>>
```

в

```
Single<List<RateCurrencyUiModel>>
```

**Проблема**

У модели для работы в UI слое есть поле String change, которое содержит разницу текущего курса, со вчерашним курсом.

Как я понял, мне нужно создать два источника данных:

```
Single<List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>> lastRateCurrency; // Курсы валют за вчерашний день
Single<List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>> newRateCurrency; // Курсы валют за сегодняшний день
```

Далее через RxJava2 нужно одновременно получать элементы из списков иточников lastRateCurrency и newRateCurrency, сравнивать курс и затем уже создавать модель для Ui слоя и возвращать её уже как:

```
Single<List<RateCurrencyUiModel>>
```

**Вопрос:**

Как мне одновременно передовать элементы списков из источников данных lastRateCurrency и newRateCurrency в третий источник данных, который по итогу вернет Single < List < RateCurrencyUiModel > >?

p.s. С RxJava2 ознакомился, возможно, я не правильно составил решение проблемы, по этому и не понимаю как её решить.

Comment: Вам необходимо использовать Single.zip(). Я могу написать Вам как это делается на kotlin, а вот для java без IDE синтаксис уже не вспомню

Comment: Я бы сделал так. добавил метод toMap() для RateCurrencyResponseModel

Сделал запрос из базы данных, для того чтобы получить RateCurrencyUiModel данные за вчера. После этого сделал запрос на сервер и получил RateCurrencyResponseModel. Сделал бы RateCurrencyResponseModel toMap в RateCurrencyUiModel, которые сохранил бы в бд с заменой (на завтра, чтобы проделать тоже самое) и прокинул RateCurrencyUiModel дальше, где требуется, все

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, спасибо, решил проблему через zip

Comment: @artur_mm опубликуйте решение как ответ, пожалуйста, Ваша проблема может возникнуть у кого-то еще)

Comment: @artur_mm `zip` не совсем то, что нужно. Например вылезет проблема, если у вас есть кэширование ответов с АПИ. Я бы использовал `combineLatest` у него такой же синтаксис, но он эммитит новые значения каждый раз, когда хотя бы один из источников поменял значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор zip объеденяет испускаемые элементы Observable в единый поток. Он дожидается поступления обоих элементов и дальше пускает их по цепочке. Это Должно подойти для ваших целей.

```
// при условии, что каждый Observable возвращает строку
// здесь вы подставите свою реализацию Single
Single<List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>> lastRateCurrency = Single.just();
Single<List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>> newRateCurrency  = Single.just();

Single.zip(lastRateCurrency, newRateCurrency, new Func2<String, String, MyResult>() {
      @Override
      public MyResult call(<List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>> lastRateCurrency, <List<RateCurrencyResponseModel>> newRateCurrency) {
          // здесь вы выполняете уже свой код по объеденению объектов
          return myResult;
      }
   }
)
```